# How to do a paged search on an Ldap server with lots of users?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, .net-core

I need to create a LDAP client that works on linux using .NET Core. I searched trought the internet and the only library that support .Net Standard is Novell.Directory.Ldap (open source, iei - https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard). Directory Service library does not have support in .Net Core for Linux, only on Windows.

I looked to the documentation and succeded to create a basic Ldap client application.

**Now the problem:** I need to synchronize a lot of users (10.000, 200.000 users) and by default my ldap server has a maximum size page 1000 (and I don't want to change it). I used a VirtualListControl in order to create pages and it works ok for 10k users.

**For 200k user it crashes with error 53 - unwilling to perform** on the LdapSortControl response.  The Novell library need a LdapSortControl in order to perform paging operation (for index) and I think that my ldap is not able to sort 200k.  The code that I used:

```
        int startIndex = 1;
        int contentCount = 0;
        int afterIndex = 10;
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            LdapVirtualListControl ctrl = new LdapVirtualListControl(startIndex, 0, afterIndex, contentCount);
            LdapSortKey[] keys = new LdapSortKey[1];
            keys[0] = new LdapSortKey("sn");
            LdapSortControl sort = new LdapSortControl(keys, true);

            LdapSearchConstraints constraints = _ldapConnection.SearchConstraints;
            constraints.setControls(new LdapControl[] { ctrl, sort});

            _ldapConnection.Constraints = constraints;
            LdapSearchResults lsc = _ldapConnection.Search(searchBase, searchScope, searchFilter, attributes, typesOnly, cons);
            while (lsc.HasMore())
            {
                try
                {
                    LdapEntry nextEntry = lsc.Next();
                    Console.WriteLine( nextEntry.DN);
                }
                catch (LdapException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.LdapErrorMessage}");
                    //Exception is thrown, go for next entry
                    continue;
                }

            }

            LdapControl[] controls = lsc.ResponseControls;
            if (controls == null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("No controls returned");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (LdapControl control in controls)
                {
                    if (control.ID == "2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.10")
                    {
                        LdapVirtualListResponse response = new LdapVirtualListResponse(control.ID, control.Critical, control.getValue());
                        startIndex += afterIndex + 1;
                        contentCount = response.ContentCount;
                        count += afterIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        } while (count <= contentCount);
```

The documentation is small and does not have enough information and I have no idea how to use  Novell library for paging in a better way. 
Is anybody here that use Novell Ldap library and have any experience with paging and also can help me? I'm disperate

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a paged query with Novell.Directory.Ldap you have to use LdapVirtualListControl as "Request" Control.

LdapVirtualListControl respects the arguments of the Ldap Sorting Request Control: VLV (Virtual List View) that are:

```
before:after:index:content_count
```

where "**before**" is the number of items that you want to be returned BEFORE the index, "**after**" the number of items that you want to be returned AFTER the index and "**content_count**" is the expected total count of items in the server. In case you do not know it, you have to use 0 as value.

If you want to return the first 5 elements via "ldapsearch" cli, you have to use: '0:4:1:0' and '0:4:5:0' for the subsequent five ones.

The LdapVirtualListControl owns a constructor with the same arguments but with a different order:

```
LdapVirtualListControl(int startIndex, int beforeCount, int afterCount, int contentCount)
```

Personally, I use this function to set the arguments correctly:

```
public static LdapSearchConstraints AddPagination(this LdapSearchConstraints constraints, int page,
            int pageSize)
{
    int startIndex = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    startIndex++;
    int beforeCount = 0;
    int afterCount = pageSize - 1;
    int contentCount = 0; //0 means that i don't know the total count

    var lvlc = new LdapVirtualListControl(startIndex, beforeCount, afterCount, contentCount);
    constraints.setControls(lvlc);
    return constraints;
}
```

After that, another issue needs your attention: if you ask for a set of data, which are positioned after the end of the data-set, you will receive back the first items of the dataset.

Explanation:

Example of data present in ldap:
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
if we ask for the set
________| 3 | 4 | 5 | <- 5 does not exists
Ldap returns:
________| 3 | 4 | 1 | <- it starts over from the beginning

To fix this issue, I remove the exceeded elements before return:

```
var lastIndex = (page * pageSize);
if (lastIndex > result.Total)
{
    var itemsToReturn = (int) (result.Total - (lastIndex - pageSize));
    if (itemsToReturn < 1)
    {
        items = new List<LdapQueryItem>();
    }
    else
    {
        items = items.Take(itemsToReturn).ToList();
    }
}
```

Finally, the function to get the totals (to execute AFTER the searchResults.HasMore() method)

```
protected int? GetTotal(LdapSearchResults searchResult)
{
    if (searchResult == null) {
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchResult));
    }
    if (searchResult.ResponseControls != null && searchResult.ResponseControls.Any())
    {
        foreach (LdapControl control in searchResult.ResponseControls)
        {
            if (control.ID == "2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.10") // the id of the response control
            {
                LdapVirtualListResponse response =
                    new LdapVirtualListResponse(control.ID, control.Critical, control.getValue());
                return response.ContentCount;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can get further insights and info on this book:
[Understanding and Deploying LDAP Directory Services](https://books.google.it/books?id=fcW1xl1BejUC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=LdapVirtualListControl%20how%20to%20use&source=bl&ots=b3cjiaTFoK&sig=1_iCXxkqE_c4wexa_bUmXssGNO0&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib4fDYk7jcAhUJ36QKHf3gChYQ6AEwBnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=LdapVirtualListControl%20how%20to%20use&f=false)

Comment: What is the purpose of searchResult.Guard(nameof(searchResult)); ? I am not able to find the Guard function in LdapSearchResults

Comment: I'm sorry: the .Guard extension is an extension to 'shortify' the common 'ArgumentNullException' check. You can replace with 'if (searchResult == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchResult));
Ps: I see now that someone have made a library with it: https://github.com/ardalis/GuardClauses
I will update the solution also.
Thank you.