# How to do a paged search on an Ldap server with > 10000 entries using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard?

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory, ldap

This is similar to [How to do a paged search on an Ldap server with lots of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805577/how-to-do-a-paged-search-on-an-ldap-server-with-lots-of-users) but the suggested solution does not work for us.

We use Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard library and we need to fetch more than 10000 entries from an Active Directory. We use the LdapVirtualListControl to handle paging, but that control requires another control: LdapSortControl. Active Directory has an default limit for sorting (10000) and will send an error 53 (unwilling to perform) if the result exceeds that limit. If the "Detect max result error" is omitted, we will instead get a LdapException: 'Unavailable Critical Extension'.

```
        // Connection
        var ldapConn = new LdapConnection()
        {
            SecureSocketLayer = true,
        };
        ldapConn.UserDefinedServerCertValidationDelegate += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        ldapConn.Connect(host, 636);            
        ldapConn.Bind(username, password);


        var searchConstraints = (LdapSearchConstraints)ldapConn.SearchConstraints.Clone();
        int contentCount = 0, count = 0, startIndex = 1, pageSize = 1000;
        bool exit;

        do
        {
            // Add Virtual List Control
            searchConstraints.setControls(new List<LdapControl>
            {
                { new LdapVirtualListControl(startIndex, 0, pageSize - 1, contentCount) },
                { new LdapSortControl(new LdapSortKey[1] { new LdapSortKey("name") },true) }
            }.ToArray());

            // Perform search
            var searchResult = ldapConn.Search(container, scope, query, null, false, searchConstraints);

            // Get entries in page
            var inPageCount = 0;
            while (searchResult.hasMore())
            {

                // Detect max result error
                LdapSortResponse ldapControl = searchResult.ResponseControls?.OfType<LdapSortResponse>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (ldapControl != null && ldapControl.ResultCode == 53) throw new LdapResultLimitExceeded(string.Format("ActiveDirectory: Ldap result limit exceeded in {0}.", container));

                searchResult.next();
                inPageCount++;
            }

            // Check for more pages 
            var control = FindResponseControl(searchResult, ActiveDirectoryService.LDAP_SERVER_VIRTUAL_LIST_VIEW_OID);
            if (control != null)
            {
                var response = new LdapVirtualListResponse(control.ID, control.Critical, control.getValue());
                startIndex += pageSize;
                contentCount = response.ContentCount;
                if (count + pageSize > contentCount) count = contentCount; else count += inPageCount;
            }
            exit = control == null;
        } while (count < contentCount && contentCount > 0 && !exit);
```

How should we handle search for more then 10000 entries?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Added a reproducible example and some more information. This example works with 10000 entries but fails with 10001 entries

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need to iterate through the result set sequentially, you don't need to use LVL. I suggest using Simple Paged Results Control (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59747510/4700228)